# How can I modify this query to order by matches?

Tags: mysql, search, tags, keyword

This query gets rows from the articles table by whether or not they have tags matching the given list of keywords.  I want to order the results by the number of tags that were matched to the search.  How would I do this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.*, 
FROM   `article` a
INNER JOIN article_tags AS at ON at.article_id = a.article_id
INNER JOIN tags AS t ON t.tag_id = at.tag_id
WHERE  t.keyword IN ("apples", "bananas", "oranges")

|--- Article Tags ---|
|--article_tag_id----|
|--article_id--------|
|-------tag_id-------|
|--------------------|

|-------Tags---------|
|------tag_id--------|
|------keyword-------|
|--------------------|
```

Comment: What do you mean: the number of distinct keyword found or the number of occurrences of these keywords? Simple example tables with the desired result are ever helpful.

Comment: Say there are two articles:  the first has tags of apples and bananas. The second has tags of apples and oranges.  Let's say a user searches with a string of "apples bananas kiwi".  The first article would appear first because it matched two tags(apples and bananas) and the second article would appear second because it only matched one tag(apples).  Is it possible to do this with the query above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something in the line

```
SELECT a.*, COUNT(t.keyword) as matches
FROM   `article` a
INNER JOIN article_tags AS at ON at.article_id = a.article_id
INNER JOIN tags AS t ON t.tag_id = at.tag_id
WHERE  t.keyword IN ("apples", "bananas", "oranges")
GROUP BY a.article_id
ORDER BY COUNT(t.keyword) DESC;
```

If you only want distinct keywords then use

```
SELECT a.*, COUNT(DISTINCT t.keyword) as matches
FROM   `article` a
INNER JOIN article_tags AS at ON at.article_id = a.article_id
INNER JOIN tags AS t ON t.tag_id = at.tag_id
WHERE  t.keyword IN ("apples", "bananas", "oranges")
GROUP BY a.article_id
ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT t.keyword) DESC;
```